# PHP ActiveRecord for PHP < 5.3

Tags: php, activerecord, phpactiverecord

I found RoR ActiveRecord very usefull. When I was looking for PHP version, I found [this](http://www.phpactiverecord.org)

Unfortunately, the use of namespace cause it work only ini PHP > 5.3. Do anyone have alternative that work for > PHP 5.3?

Comment: There are many more ActiveRecord libraries for PHP. You'll find a few here [Good PHP ORM library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library) between the ORMs. A lightweight one is [Paris atop Idiorm](http://j4mie.github.com/idiormandparis/). But you'll have to check out how much features you need.

Comment: PHP 5.2 is not maintained anymore, upgrade or invite your hosting provider to upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

I 'am using [PhpActiveRecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/) too. I can suggest you [miniOrm](https://github.com/MrManchot/miniOrm) , but it is not so good as phpactiverecord. Just take a look.